# create a nested row in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

for some reason i receive the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined"

whenever i try to add a nested row, to an existing row in a simple datatables table.

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-plus',function(event)
    {
        getRowId(event);
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var row = dTable.row( tr ); 
        if ( row.child.isShown() )
        {
    // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else    
        {
        // Open this row (the fnFormatDetails() function would return the data to be shown)
        row.child( fnFormatDetails() ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        }
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $(this).addClass('glyphicon-minus');

   });
```

the table instance:

```
var dTable=$('#campaign-table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":"testserverside.php",
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
        //some code goes here
    },
});
```

i am using the Datatables version 1.10.10.

Comment: Where are you trying to add a nested row? Is it possible to create a fiddle?

Comment: i created a fiddle, but the table is loaded by ajax so you wont be able to view the result, at any rate hope it helps:
https://jsfiddle.net/uaf8Lfxm/

Comment: @Wolfazb - You can use **http://myjson.com/** to create AJAX loads in jsfiddles ...